# Combining information from one raster with another raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I have two rasters, A and A1.

Raster A is the image below that is greenish and has the following attribute table:

[image: A table]
[image: Raster A]

The table has two fields that I need: Value and class_name

Raster A1 is the image that is purplish and has the attribute table

[image: A1 table]
[image: Raster A1]

A1's table has information on the part of raster A that is missing. This has been coded as 999999 in A1's table which I have circled in yellow below

My task is to fill in the missing part of A with the information in A1 (the Value in A1 that has been coded 99999). In other words, I need to expand the attribute table of A with another row for 9999999 found in the raster A1.

What is the quickest method to do this?

I have tried the Sample tool and it takes too long (I have to do this for over 10 rasters). I have tried Mosaic, but it does not give me both Value and class_name fields in the attribute table of A.

Comment: Try to use CON in raster calculator, e.g Con("A1"=999, "A", "A1")

Comment: Spot on @FelixIP, you should make that an answer.. however I have just one question: In your list there I can't see the descriptions for the values in the 'to' raster, are they identical? i.e. value n in A1 has the same class in A... if the classes don't match you will need to do some translating/reclassifying. Having the numbers matching is **critical** to the success of this operation.

Comment: Based on question, it seems classes are the same in both rasters. Values look similar as well